# Battery suddenly drops to 0%

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, battery

My battery started dropping down from around 35% to 0% suddenly . This started happening as soon as I installed ubuntu 12.04 ..I am using a lenovo Z510 laptop with windows 8.1 as default OS..Any ideas on how to improve the battery life?

To be more specific ubuntu was installed but not working and My laptop is a new one with warranty so the odds of battery failure may be less.

Comment: retain battery life? no no thats not the issue.  Sounds like a problem with reading your batterys actual capacity

Comment: @Virusboy  , I dont think therez a problem with that

Comment: So it does it with wondoze?